# Android: Have PushNotifications an income-timestamp?

Tags: android, notifications, timestamp, push

we are using the Gcm Push Notification Server from our externel Java Project to send push notifications to an Android Phone.

On this phone there is an app running that reacts on this notification. The app needs to know when the push notification arrived at the phone (in order to calculate a 120sec timer beginning at this point of time).

Is there a possibility in the andorid app to find out when the push notification arrived...some kind of creation/imcome/recieved timestamp?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.currentTimeMillis()` in your `GcmListenerService`'s `onMessageReceived()` method.